# ¿Cómo genero un certificado SSL para un servidor de Apache Tomcat mediante keyTool?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, server, despliegue

Buenas estoy intentando generar un certificado SSL mediante el comando Keytool.
Todo sale bien y ahora tengo generado un .keystore:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo en la configuración server.xml lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando abro mi servidor con https recibo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi KeyTool List :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa TODOS los archivos en ese directorio con algo como `ls -al`, pues esa opción `-keystore` guarda el resultado en un archivo `.keystore` que puede pasar como arcivo oculto en configuraciones por defecto del file manager que uses

Comment: Ahora tengo creado el .keystore y he configurado la ruta pero no funciona

Comment: Alguien puede anydesk? me estoy demorando como 4h XD

Comment: He editado explicando lo que me ocurre ahora

Comment: Pon en tu pregunta los fragmentos de los logs de Tomcat que veas que están relacionados con tu problema. De paso, nos cuentas qué versión de apache tomcat estás usando. Y de paso, valida el contenido del keystore con `keytool -list`.

Comment: Edité la pregunta con lo que me devuelve keytool -list y es Apache tomcat 9. No sé hacer eso de los logs

Comment: Alguien me echa una mano?

Comment: En donde estás editando el `/conf/server.xml`, hay una carpeta logs. Ahí están los logs, revisa que hay, seguro salen algunos errores relacionados

Comment: No me sale ninguna carpeta de logs ahí en ese directorio conf.

Comment: Tengo un directorio logs en la raíz de el directorio pero todo apunta a estar bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142154/discussion-between-aphans-and-alfabravo).

Answer (score 1):

El último párametro indica el nombre del archivo y puedes definir un directorio en el cual se creará, no uses él signo "=", este es un ejemplo:

```
Keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore c:/data/certicados/certificadoAphans
```

Define un directorio en el cual desees se genere el certificado. **Lo que puede estar sucediendo en este caso es que no encuentre la ruta en donde se creará o no tiene permisos, define un directorio donde tengas permisos de escritura**.

Comment: Ya tengo un .keystore creado y lo he configurado en el conector pero no funciona...

Comment: :-0 Veo que editaste completamente el contenido de tu pregunta original, te sugiero crees una nueva pregunta si tienes una duda diferente a lo que publicas en tus preguntas, saludos.

Comment: Perdona, no sabía eso pensaba que se podía editar así